# Can't get vpn_url from Netatmo Welcome camera

Tags: api, camera, vpn

I'm developing an app that shows the live video from a Welcome camera. The problem is that I can't get the vpn_url from my camera. When I try to get this info from the gethomedata api call I get the following object within cameras json array.

```
[ { id: 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX',
    type: 'NACamera',
    status: 'on',
    sd_status: 'on',
    alim_status: 'on',
    name: 'MyFirstCamera' } ]
```

It is not the same response that documentation shows:(https://dev.netatmo.com/dev/resources/technical/reference/welcome/gethomedata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the scope access_camera ? without the scope access_camera you will not be able to access the live video from the camera.

The scope must be : access_camera

[Here](https://dev.netatmo.com/dev/resources/technical/guides/authentication/clientcredentials) you can find more information

Comment: I have vpn_url but when I access it gives 403 Forbidden. Have you any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are developing an app to be used by other accounts, you need to request the access_camera scope from Netatmo.

> The scope access_camera grants you access to very sensitive data and is delivered by Netatmo teams on a per-app basis, after a very thorough check.

When developing, the account used to create the netatmo application should be the same that has the devices.